# Executar outro aplicativo assim que receber um SMS

Tags: java, android, sms, android-intent

Preciso chamar um aplicativo já instalado em meu celular assim que receber um SMS de um determinado número.

Todo o código desse aplicativo já está pronto, mas não sei como chamá-lo a partir dessa mensagem.

Devo usar `Intent` ou algo parecido?

Comment: Acredito que seja através do uso de Broadcast Receivers. Dê uma pesquisada nisso que te falei. Acho que seja isso porque no meu projeto quando eu quis executar uma ação quando um download no Android completasse tive que usar isso. Se não me engano você registra broadcasts para executar determinadas ações de acordo com eventos do sistema.

Comment: Recomendo este link: http://blog.hachitecnologia.com.br/mobile/trabalhando-com-broadcast-receivers-no-android

Comment: Justamente sobre Broadcast Receivers que estou pesquisando agora. Obrigado

Comment: Aqui tem um bom exemplo de como receber a notificação: http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando um `BroadcastReceiver` é possível interceptar as mensagens que estão chegando no dispositivo.

Primeiramente você vai precisar da seguinte permissão no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`, nesse caso eu coloquei para aumentar a prioridade isso vai ajudar caso você tenha outra aplicação (de terceiro) que captura SMS, assim ele terá privilégio no momento de receber:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<receiver android:name="com.example.smsinterceptor.MessageReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`BroadcastReceiver MessageReceiver.java`, aqui no *receiver* eu obtenho a mensagem e todos os detalhes através dos extras. Só tome cuidado que se sua mensagem for composta por mais de um SMS você vai ter que tratar; no código abaixo só trato uma mensagem. Também após detectar que é a mensagem que quero eu uso o `abortBroadcast()`, isso vai impedir que outras aplicações capturem essa mesma mensagem (desde que a prioridade esteja ok no *manifest*):

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String TAG = MessageReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private String NUMBER_FILTER = "3784";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Receiver activated");

        Bundle extraContent = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messagePdus = (Object[]) extraContent.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messagePdus[0]);

        if (smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress().endsWith(NUMBER_FILTER)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message intercepted: "+ smsMessage.getMessageBody());
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou tento problemas para abrir uma activity a partir do recebimento da mensagem, vi em alguns lugares que é uma pratica incorreta, mas para essa aplicação preciso de uma resposta muita rápida, então preciso que seja feito dessa forma. O que preciso é abrir uma página logo após o recebimento da mensagem usando o navegador e por algum detalhe não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Teria como você postar mais detalhes? Você esta fazendo o startActivity com a flag newtask?

Comment: então, o código até mostra a mensagem como uma notificação, mas além da mensagem preciso abrir a página e para abrir a página estou tentando algo do tipo:

//Intent WebIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse ("http://192.168.0.157"));
                //startActivity (WebIntent);

vou editar a parte do código

Comment: Provavelmente o problema que você esta tendo é que esta tentando iniciar um activity a partir de um broadcast receiver, ai você vai precisar colocar essa flag: WebIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Eae me avisa se deu certo?

Comment: Funcionou sim. Vou tentar colocar o código aqui. Meu problema era o seguinte...Eu tinha um móduto GPRS conectado a um arduíno, então ao pressionar a campainha era enviado uma mensagem de texto pro meu cel, ao receber a mensagem de texto o celular deveria abrir automaticamente com o link da minha camera ip. E deu certo

Comment: Que bacana! Posta sim parece ser interessante! Abs

Comment: @user8728 Se a resposta foi suficiente para seu problema poderia aceitar a questão?